# Forward touch event to dynamically attached view, without lifting finger

Tags: android

I have a problem I am struggling with a while now.

I have a Layout with a Button and a container in it.

```
<FrameLayout ... >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        ...
    />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/overlayContainer"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

My goal is that as I long-press the button, I attach a **custom view** `MyCustomView`to the container and keep the finger pressed.
All the following (`ACTION_MOVE`, `ACTION_UP`) events should then ideally be dispatched to and evaluated by `MyCustomView`.

`MyCustomView` works like a circular flyout menu: it overlays, dims the background, and shows some options. You then slide your pressed finger to the option, lift it up, and it triggers a result.

```
mButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // attach custom view to overlayContainer
        // simplified code for demonstration
        overlayContainer.addView(new MyCustomView());
        return true;
    }
});
```

Right now I don't see any option to "steal" the `ACTION_DOWN`-Event (which is required to start the event flow to a view) from the Button as I'm above it.
Nor does it work to manually generate and dispatch a `ACTION_DOWN`-Event in `MyCustomView` as I attach it.

While researching I found this post here, it basically is the same requirement, but for iOS (also does not provide an elegant solution, other that an click capturing overlay view) ): [How to preserve touch event after new view is added by long press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031535/how-to-preserve-touch-event-after-new-view-is-added-by-long-press?rq=1)

Note that I want to avoid some kind of global overlay over the main view, I would like the solution to be as pluggable and portable as possible.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Isn't TouchDelegate what you're looking for?

Comment: You mean setting TouchDelegate on the Button and passing CustomView to it? Interesting thought ...

Comment: you could try that,  but also you can see the sources of TD how it dispatches MotionEvents and do it by yourself

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look into it

Comment: Yes, TouchDelegate was the key! Thank you. Will post an answer once I cleaned everything up. Any way I could vote your hint up more than once? :)

Comment: yes, you could buy me a beer ;-)

Comment: I would, have yet to find the button for it :-)

Comment: ok Steffen, but if you are from Germany, cuold you recommend some good german job search engine, preferably Berlin/Munich area? monster de ?

Comment: You can have a look at [XING](https://www.xing.com/), it's quite popular here, or LinkedIn. I heard about monster, but no personal experience. Freelancermap is also worth a mention.

Comment: muchos danke indeed ;) i'll try them out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question after the hint in the comments:

I solved it using a bare stripped version of `TouchDelegate` (had to extend it, since it unfortunetaly is no interface - `setTouchDelegate` only accepts `TouchDelegate` (sub)classes. Not 100%  clean, but works great.

```
public class CustomTouchDelegate extends TouchDelegate {

    private View mDelegateView;

    public CustomTouchDelegate(View delegateView) {
        super(new Rect(), delegateView);
        mDelegateView = delegateView;
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return mDelegateView.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Then in my onLongClick method:

```
mButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // attach custom view to overlayContainer, simplified for demonstration

        MyCustomView myMenuView = new MyCustomView()
        mButton.setTouchDelegate(new CustomTouchDelegate(myMenuView));

        // What's left out here is to mButton.setTouchDelegate = null,
        // as soon as the temporary Overlay View is removed

        overlayContainer.addView(myMenuView);
        return true;
    }
});
```

This way, all my `ACTION_MOVE` events from the Button are delegated to `MyCustomView` (and may or may not need some translation of the coordinates) - et voilà.

Thanks to pskink for the hint.